# Assigning values during conditional statements

Tags: postgresql

I have been trying to insert values from table avergeclient into a table "finalresult", but I am getting syntax errors.

I tried to search online for a solution, also checked the documentation but I could not find a solution to my problem, sorry for duplicate questions if I did not find one. At first, I was trying to use the as statement, then tried ":=" from the documentation, but none works.

```sql
INSERT INTO finalresult
select avg,
CASE WHEN avergeclient.client_id = finalresult.clinet_id AND averageclient.month = finalresult.month
THEN total := avg
ELSE total := 0
END
FROM avergeclient;
```

Error I'm getting is

`LINE 4: THEN total := avg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve with the variable assignment. But maybe you are probably looking for a column alias:

```
INSERT INTO finalresult (avg, total)
select avg,
       CASE 
         WHEN avergeclient.client_id = finalresult.clinet_id AND averageclient.month = finalresult.month
            THEN avg
         ELSE 0
       END as total
FROM avergeclient;
```

Comment: Hi! My goal was to assign the column of avg from avergelient to the column total in finalresult on some condition; so if both client_id and month equals, then avg will be assigned to that specific row of client_id and month, if not equal, then 0 will be assign to that row in finalresult. I just tried testing your code and it gave me ```ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "finalresult"``` in line 4.

Comment: and also in finalresult there is not column named avg, only total.

Comment: I guess I messed up the idea, I should have used UPDATE for it, thanks!